# Timing in Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, timing

I'm currently going through the [Project Euler's](http://projecteuler.net/) problems and I'm solving them both in C# and Scheme (the [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) implementation). I know C# but I'm learning Scheme as I go along.

Now, on top of having the correct results for the problems, I like to come up with the fastest possible solution I can think of. To that effect, in C# I use [StopWatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) to measure the performance of my code. Is there a similar Scheme library / functionality to time code execution?

Comment: Which implementation of Scheme are you using? Such a function isn't part of the standard core Scheme, but would be provided as an additional function by whoever implemented your Scheme environment.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just enclose the whole part you want to time in the `time` expression (this works in most implementations, including Racket):

```
(time (rest-of-program))
```

You can also use the Unix command `time` if you're on Linux/OSX/BSD/etc., e.g.

```
time ./my_program
```

Comment: Also, if you want to capture the times (e.g. to store them in a table or save them to disk) you can use time-apply, which returns multiple values.

Comment: Rafe: This is *almost* what I want. From the documentation, I found it reports the milliseconds for execution http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/time.html#(def._((quote._~23~25kernel)._time-apply)) . Is there a way to get to a finer time interval, like `StopWatch` does for C#?

Comment: @Joce how much finer does it get? E.g. what unit does C# use?

Comment: I use `ticks`. From the `StopWatch` documentation (  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.frequency.aspx), this is a machine dependent unit. On my machine, the frequency is equal to 2604160, thus a tick is roughly 384 nanoseconds, roughly 3 orders of magnitude smaller than a millisecond.  Is there a timer that can get me that in Scheme?